# Removing mime type icon from image using CSS, possible?

Tags: html, css, mime-types, font-awesome, show-hide

I'm currently using some CSS to append font-awesome icons as mime types for uploaded files and or links that end in .pdf, .xls, .docx, etc.

I should have prefaced this entire post with this comment I made:

**Ok, I should have mentioned that this is a WordPress site where users are able to upload and link images via the Media Uploader. Trying to automate this process so that (once delivered) the editor won't have to add HTML code to the visual editor. That being said, all WP images have a class assigned to them that's ".wp-image-*", would it be possible to use that WP class to filter the icons?**

My CSS looks like this:

```
a[href$=".pdf"]::after {
  font-family: "fontawesome";
  content: "\0020\f1c1";
  color: inherit;
  font-weight: 400
}
```

This solution works exactly as I want it to with one exception... it appends the mime type icon to **images that LINK to** a .pdf not just text links.

How to remove or not display the font-awesome icon on images only? That is the question. I have tried a number of different CSS solutions and have come up with either removing the entire image that is linked to the .pdf, or nothing at all.

Looking for some guidance here, would prefer the solution to be CSS **but am open to whatever will work the best**(php, js, jquery, etc).

HERES AN EXAMPLE:

(text link)

```
<a href="example.pdf">Example PDF</a>
```

This works as expected.

This is the problem...

(image link below)

```
 <a href="example.pdf">
   <img src="example.jpg" alt="example pdf" />
 </a>
```

When the link wraps an image, it appends the font awesome icon to the image. How to stop the font awesome icon on images wrapped in links only?

My page code looks like this (not verbatim), also, using BootStrap Library:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="main_content">
     <!-- Then there are the usual basic tags found in WordPress content such as <p><h1><blockquote> etc but the containing div is "main_content", no <div>'s before image -->
    <p>
      <a href="http://example-document.pdf">
       <img class="alignright size-medium wp-image-639 img-responsive" src="http://example-image.jpg" alt="Alt Title" srcset="http://example-image.jpg 232w, http://example-image.jpg 613w" sizes="(max-width: 232px) 100vw, 232px">
      </a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How does _just text links_ look like? ... And what do you mean by _How to remove or not display the font-awesome icon on images only?_ ... Post a sample that does not work how you want and we'll see if we can help

Comment: updated with example.

Comment: @LGSon thank you again not only for the solution but for the outside the box thinking and knowledge transfer. I learned a lot of useful information from your examples and comments. I was in the process of creating a php function to append your "data-hasimg" attribute to linked files but then you fired up that JS example and was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for taking the time and effort. Much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you and I'm happy to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve it with the existing markup you'll need a parent selector, and those does not exist (yet).

A workaround could be to wrap the text in the text only links with a `span` and update the CSS rule with the `:not(img)` selector

```css
a[href$=".pdf"] :not(img)::after {
  content: " X";
  color: red;
  font-weight: 400
}
```

```html
<a href="example.pdf"><span>Example PDF</span></a>
<br>
 <a href="example.pdf">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/100" alt="example pdf" />
 </a>
```

Or add a `data-*` attribute on the links that contain an image

```css
a[href$=".pdf"]:not([data-hasimg])::after {
  content: " X";
  color: red;
  font-weight: 400
}
```

```html
<a href="example.pdf">Example PDF</a>
<br>
 <a href="example.pdf" data-hasimg>
   <img src="http://placehold.it/100" alt="example pdf" />
 </a>
```

If you can't change markup, here is a script sample

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a[href$=".pdf"]');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  if (links[i].children.length == 0) {
    links[i].classList.add('icon');
  }
}
```

```css
a[href$=".pdf"].icon::after {
  content: " X";
  color: red;
  font-weight: 400
}
```

```html
<a href="example.pdf">Example PDF</a>
<br>
<a href="example.pdf">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100" alt="example pdf" />
</a>
```

Comment: Ok, I should have mentioned that this is a WordPress site where users are able to upload and link images via the Media Uploader.  Trying to automate this process so that (once delivered) the editor won't have to add HTML code to the visual editor. That being said, all WP images have a class assigned to them that's ".wp-image-*", would it be possible to use that WP class to filter the icons?

Comment: @ben.kaminski No, as they target the image, which is a child of the link, which would need a parent selector.

Comment: Can the parent selector be the containing div? For example, the containing div has an id of "#main_content"? Thanks for your help thus far @LGSon

Comment: @ben.kaminski Show me how that would look like, add it to your question.

Comment: Will do @LGSon.

Comment: @ben.kaminski The problem here is that whether there should be an icon or not, is if the anchor/link contain an image, so in this case it doesn't matter if there is a parent div, and as the _selector query_ will be "add an icon to the anchor/link if it does not include an image", and for that a parent selector is needed, to target the anchor/link if its child is an image. With my above 1:st sample the `span` gets the icon as it's not an image. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: @ben.kaminski What I mean with a parent selector would be to try to say to the image, "if I am an image inside a link, tell my parent (the link) to not get an icon", and if this could be done, problem solved, but it can't as of today ... well, you can using a script, but not with CSS

Comment: yes, makes sense... working on a fix based on your input now.

Comment: @ben.kaminski Added a 3:rd sample using script, just in case it comes down to that

Comment: Third times the charm @LGSon!!! Thank you... saved the day with the javascript solution!

Answer (score 0):

Place your text in a span and give it a class name like this:

```
a[href$=".pdf"] .text:after {
  font-family: "fontawesome";
  content: "\0020\f1c1";
  color: inherit;
  font-weight: 400
}


<a href="example.pdf"><span class="text">Example PDF</span></a>

<a href="example.pdf">
   <img src="example.jpg" alt="example pdf" />
 </a>
```